# Getting xml element name from unmarshalled java object with JAXB

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

I have fields *annotated* with `@XmlElement(name="xxx")` in my Java model.

Is there a way to get the xml element name programatically?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Say we have annotated entity

```
 @XmlRootElement
 public class Product {
      String name;      

      @XmlElement(name="sss")
      public void setName(String name) {
           this.name = name;
      }
}
```

Code below will print "sss" using [java Reflection API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/package-summary.html). Here 'product' is an object of Product class

```
import java.lang.reflect.Method;
...
Method m = product.getClass().getMethod("setName",String.class);
XmlElement a = m.getAnnotation(XmlElement.class);
String nameValue = a.name();
System.out.println(nameValue);
```

If you need to get @XmlElement annotation attribute from **private field**, you could use something like this:

```
Field nameField = product.getClass().getDeclaredField("name");
nameField.setAccessible(true);
XmlElement a = nameField.getAnnotation(XmlElement.class);
String nameValue = a.name();
System.out.println(nameValue);
```

Comment: +1 - An important thing to note is that if the annotation is just `@XmlElement` then the value of the name parameter is going to be `##default`.  In this case you will need to apply the rules from the JAXB (JSR-222) specification to the property name to derive the element name.

Comment: @BlaiseDoughan Can you expound more on using the JAXB to derive the element name?