# How do we get field name if we have field as below. @XmlElement(required = true)

Tags: java, jaxb, nsxmlelement

How do we get field name if we have field as below.

```
@XmlElement(required = true) 
protected String code;
```

If i try to get as:

```
Field f = clazz.getDeclaredField(field); 
XmlElement xmlElement = f.getAnnotation(XmlElement.class);  
xmlElement.name() // returns as ##default instead of code.
```

Comment: Note that using the default name can be harmful. Renaming a field is easy. It can be initiated elsewhere than the annotated field declaration. And it would not be backwards compatible with existing XML representations.

Answer (score 0):

### default just means that the property name from the Java bean is used:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/annotation/XmlElement.html#name%28%29

There are others posts here that deal with the same problem, none of them seems really to explain how to get the value. Here is one:
[Getting xml element name from unmarshalled java object with JAXB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23016557/getting-xml-element-name-from-unmarshalled-java-object-with-jaxb)